# Fetching Custom Document Properties in Excel using C# is slow

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, com-interop, excel-addins

I am fetching custom properties from woorkbook using this method:

```
var wb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Open(file.FullName);
wb.Windows[1].Visible = false;
if (wb != null)
{
    foreach (var prop in wb.CustomDocumentProperties)
    {
        try
        {
           Console.WriteLine(prop.Name.ToString());
           Console.WriteLine(prop.Value.ToString());
           Properties.Add(new CustomDocumentProperty { Key = prop.Name.ToString(), Value = prop.Value.ToString() });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    wb.Close(false);
}
```

This method works, but the problem is that it is really slow in fetching the properties before executing the loop. So is there any way to speed this up? I have tried to look at other posts on this site, but I havent seen anyone mention this issue. Please let me know if I need to post anymore code. (Properties is a list of a custom class)

Comment: Is it the writing to the console that's slow?

Comment: No, the process of fetching the properties. It takes a long time before the program executes the loop.